# Actual Reverse Bubbling to the leaf in the DOM

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I really do like events in Javascript, especially with bubbling - but I have been wondering whether it is possible to get the reverse bubbling effect like reaching children through events instead of parents. I know there is the capturing phase - but this really only works for click and the likes and not custom events.

So, is it possible at all?

Thanks!
Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for *event delegation* or at least something related to what event delegation uses: The `target` property of the event object. Regardless of where you hook the event, the `target` property reflects the element the event was dispatched to. That means you can hook an event on an ancestor element, but then look at the `target` property to determine the descendant the event was dispatched to. Here's an example *(I'm using `click` here, but there's a custom event example later)*:

```js
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e) {
    console.log("Element clicked: " + e.target.id);
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<p>Click either of the child elements below:</p>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first-child">first child</div>
  <div id="second-child">second child</div>
</div>
```

There's also `currentTarget` which is the element where you hooked the event (it's also `this` if you hook up the event via `addEventListener` and you don't use a bound or arrow function).

This means that starting from an event that's reached an ancestor, you can follow its entire path through the descendant elements by looping on the target element's `parentNode`:

```js
document.getElementById("root").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e) {
    var path = [];
    for (var node = e.target; node != this; node = node.parentNode) {
      path.push(node.id);
    }
    console.log("Path: " + path.join(", "));
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<p>Click below:</p>
<div id="root">
  <div id="branch-1-level-1">
    <div id="branch-1-level-2">
      <div id="branch-1-level-3">
        <div id="branch-1-level-4-child-1">branch-1-level-4-child-1</div>
        <div id="branch-1-level-4-child-2">branch-1-level-4-child-2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="branch-2-level-1">
    <div id="branch-2-level-2">
      <div id="branch-2-level-3">
        <div id="branch-2-level-4-child-1">branch-2-level-4-child-1</div>
        <div id="branch-2-level-4-child-2">branch-2-level-4-child-2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example with a custom event:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("#root, #child2"),
  function(element) {
    element.addEventListener(
      "my-custom-event",
      function(e) {
        console.log("Element " + this.id + " got " + e.type + " on " + e.target.id);
      },
      false
    );
  }
);

// Fire a custom bubbling event at child2
var e = new CustomEvent("my-custom-event", {
  bubbles: true
});
document.getElementById("child2").dispatchEvent(e);
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">child1</div>
    <div id="child2">child2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```